# Video games periodically stutter

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, graphics, lag

About 2 months ago, video games on my computer have suddenly started to periodically stutter. Normally, I run them fine, but now, about every 1 minute, the game starts to run at approx. 5 FPS for about a minute, then it reverts back to normal performance.

This happen to ALL video games on my computer, including browser flash games, strangely enough. However, video such as Twitch or YouTube still works fine. I should also note that sound still works find while stuttering, and is not affected by the lag.

I suspect this may have something to do with the GPU (GeForce 9500 GT, in my case), judging from the above symptoms, but I'm not certain. I have tried updating the video card drivers, but that didn't help. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of your GPU?

Comment: GeForce 9500 GT

Comment: Do you know that your graphics card is 4 years old?

Comment: I'm aware. Do you really think it may have just kicked the bucket?

Comment: Did you change some settings of the GPU?

Comment: No, I didn't. Which ones should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your card suffered some form of damage and lags or stutters when that part is accessed. It does not always have to result in a crash of your computer when your video card accesses bad parts of its hardware. I suggest trying a new video card. I imagine the problems will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

### Reset your graphics card settings

It is common problem that when you overclock or change some of the settings of the GPU, video games or other media apps start to shutter. Also, your graphics card is 4 years old.

Maybe your PC is not well ventilated?

Sources:

- https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/483211/9500-gt-stuttering/?offset=2
- https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/524350/nvidia-9500-gt-strange-stuttering-/?offset=2
- http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=282596